# Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: hibernate, spring, gwt, maven

I have an error. I'm working with GWT, Spring, Hibernate, Maven.

When May a call to a webservice debugging I see that if you bring the data requested, but no longer come into view, when he travels back to the view where the call was made AsyncCallback, goes like the limbo, and I ended dialing:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

ayudenme took all night trying to solve it and I see nothing but the solution is the GRATEFUL in too

Answer (score 0):

I'd attach Visual VM 1.3.3 to the process that throws the exception and examine what's happening with the heap.

You don't need advice here; you need more data and visibility.  No one could answer based on what you've posted.  We're blind, but so are you.  More information will clarify the situation.

Comment: look at the flijo is like this:

call GWT AsyncCallback class .-

servie.getMethod (AsyncCallback) {}

interface:
@ RemoteServiceRelativePath ("rpc / service")
public interface Service extends RemoteService;

Class that implements the interface and makes the call to the webservice .-

here if you and does everything returns exact location.

but when he goes back to the GWT class .-

It takes a good brand until the error said. when it was to do everything.

Comment: You can also try to analyse a heap dump (via jmap). If you are using Eclipse, there is a nice plugin called 'Memory Analyzer' which provides useful info like bottle necks, heap usage etc.